# Temporarily remove electrical panel off wall

Tags: electrical-panel, basement-refinishing

Good evening,

I am removing the wood paneling in my basement the previous owner put in due to water damage and have an issue with the electrical panel and wood board being attached to the panel. Is it safe to temporarily remove that to replace/remove the 2x4 and panel behind it?

Comment: There's no issue temporarily removing a panel per se, but there may well be issues removing the things connected to it.  To know that, we'd need to know what they are.  Also, I'm not clear if you're needing to disconnect all wiring from it, remove it from the area completely, and then rewire it afterwards, or if you're hoping to move it a bit with the wiring still connected just to get behind it.  And I agree with Steve, pictures would be very useful.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the situation?

Comment: Thanks for answering so soon! I do not want to disconnect the wiring. I just want to move the box off the wall so I can remove the water damaged material behind it. I will post pictures in the morning. Thanks all

Comment: in theory it's fine, but if wires or conduit is tight, it might be difficult or impossible to do without some disconnection.

Comment: I agree with DanDavis. If there is enough flex in the wiring the panel can be removed and rehung. I have done this to isolate a panel that was directly attached to concrete. Adding furring strips and 3/4 plywood to anchor the panel to. After fixing your panel make sure all cables and conduits are properly secured. Make sure not to stress the feeders especially as they are large conductors and even clamps don’t fully isolate movement inside the panel.